# USB ASCII input without ICs?

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit

I think I have the basic knowledge to build an 8-bit controller consisting of 8 buttons and logic gates to give out an 8-bit signal. My problem is, I have 9 outputs without counting 0 or 9. That is 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111, 1000.

But I want to know how is it that this information can all go through a single USB Data+.

Comment: Sorry, but even after reading it three times I do not know what you want.

Comment: USB being differential, it won't go through a single USB Data+, It will require D- too.... And Agree with Tom!

Comment: Do you just want to make use of the USB physical layer, or do you want this communication to actually be USB protocol compatible?

Comment: I count 8 outputs as you've listed them. And you've shown them as 4 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_communication) data (e.g. four GPIO outputs each with logic 1 or 0 voltage levels)

In which case you want to convert that parallel data to [serial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication) format which can be transmitted over a single "TX" wire (plus "signal ground" and various other control wires).

You can do that in software in your controller or you can buy various chips to do the job. Foe example the well knowm [FTDI USB to parallel FIFO](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT240X.html)